# Magento Go Questions

Tags: discussion

As all 7 billions of us already know, [Magento Go is going to "go"](http://go.magento.com/) starting Feb 1st 2015.
And we have a few questions related to [magento-go](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-go).
I know Feb 1 2015 is a long way away, but I just wanted to ask this before we forget about it.
**What should we do about the questions tagged [magento-go](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-go)?**
I assume we are going to allow them until the end of the year, but after that?
Assuming this website is not going to be shut down until then, I propose to close them with a dedicated reason. Something like

> This is off topic because Magento-go is gone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will make sense to close them all as they will be never answered.

It will actually make sense to even delete them as they will be never helpful to anyone but I think it will be not fair to take reputation away earned with these questions/answers.

Comment: Seams fair......

Comment: Sounds about right to me. Of course you guys should make the decision for your site, but for what it's worth, Web Apps [discussed a similar issue](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1090/how-should-questions-about-defunct-services-be-handled) a few years ago and came to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

In business it's not over until the fat lady sings -- which means that it's business as usual until it's not (Feb 1st). There could be a sudden turnaround, such as eBay selling whole Go business to some hosting company. I also expect a surge of migration related question at some point (I've already seen few of them on Twitter).

Comment: I totally agree, I wasn't talking about closing them now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this tag should be deleted now or it can be deleted after 2-3 months because "Go" is "gone" now and there would be no further usage of this.